# See all files in a target’s membership in Xcode

Tags: xcode, target

How to see a list of files that have membership in a target in Xcode?

I know I can click each file individually in the project navigator, and use the Inspector to see if that file has **Target Membership** target item checked. But how to review for all files rather than one-by-one?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Look in the Build Phases for that target.

[image]

Comment: how to add all files in a target to another target at once ?